# npm install - but just touch ALL the urls and check for 403s

Tags: npm, installation

Is there a command to do something like this

```
$ npm install --touch-urls
npm OK.  200 234 accessible end points (see 'log.mcloggin.log' for details
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/someevent.ts
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://frogio.org/mypackage.ts
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - GET https://blah.org/thingie.ts
```

that could tell me all the end points my proxy/firewall/network is denied in one go? So that I can request access from the networking team to the 3 I don't have? All in one ticket? At the moment I have to `npm install` and I only get the top one, one at a time - so it takes 3 tickets - as it will stop at the first 403 until it is resolved - and then (and ***only*** then) do I get the next one and to be honest it takes our team 7 -10 days to get network access sorted. So 3 tickets one by one 'in series' is no joke.